# How can i call cpprofiler in choco-solver for contrainst programming profiling

Tags: java, choco

I found this on choco-solver documentation but i do not know how use it with provided choco-solver sample program in order to profile.

NB: I already install cpprofiller in my machine and launch it. So it start a tcp server on port 6565.

Need help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure  your code looks like:

```java
try (CPProfiler profiler = new CPProfiler(s1.getSolver(), true)) {
   solver.findSolution();
}
```

Then, you should start CPProfiler first and then run run Java program.
Once you go back to the CPProfiler interface, you should see the search tree being updated.